# How to find common set of element between groups?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following :

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------+
|    day     |                       items                    |
+------------+------------------------------------------------+
| 2020-02-26 | {6602754, 5292041, 7053324, 7127053, 6594574}  |
| 2020-02-27 | {6610945, 6602754, 7094278, 6610953, 5947404}  |
| 2020-02-28 | {6602754, 7094278, 6610953, 6594574, 7086094}  |
| 2020-02-29 | {6610945, 6602754, 5292041, 7053324, 6594574}  |
| 2020-03-01 | {6610945, 6602754, 6873089, 6594566, 6594574}  |
| 2020-03-02 | {6602754, 6578185, 6561809, 6553624, 6610970}  |
| 2020-03-03 | {6602754, 7168009, 6561809, 7094293, 6553624}  |
| 2020-03-04 | {6602754, 7061506, 6905861, 6103047, 6578185}  |
+------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to retrieve common elements among day. It means items that appear in all days. Items contain set of items. Any leads in this regard would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it:

```
df_dict = df.set_index('day').to_dict()['items']
result = set.intersection(*(df_dict[key] for key in df_dict.keys()))
```